# Animate series of images blocks independently of each other

Tags: jquery, css, html, animation

I am relatively new to HTML/JavaScript programming but have done some in Objective C in the past

Simplified Scenario:

```
<div id="inline-blocked-images">
<img id="one" style="display:none" width="100px" height="100px" />
<img id="two" style="display:none" width="100px" height="100px" />
<img id="three" style="display:none" width="100px" height="100px" />
</div>
```

Initially all images are hidden. Now I want to show them one by one from left to right but with animation. In jQuery I am doing below for each image via setInterval of 400ms duration ..so effectively it will go like below

```
$('#one').show();
$('#one').animate( { 'width':50, 'height':50}, {duration:200});
```

Problem is after first image  each subsequent image cause vertical movement of previous images. That is final size of all images is 50 x 50 px when next to it a new 100 x 100 px image is shrunk to 50 x 50 via animation all previous 50 x 50 move down and then up again to align with new 50 x 50 guy on their right.

What should be done to make sure animation is only impacting the new image and not all previous one? How such things are achieved in HTML/js land?

Comment: I tried this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/pVX2F/1/) and it is working fine. Not sure if I understood your question clearly.

Comment: Not clear what you are looking for... check this: http://jsfiddle.net/U4ueK/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VERTICALLY STACKED: http://jsfiddle.net/ccarterc1984/v69wd/1/

HORIZONTALLY STACKED: http://jsfiddle.net/ccarterc1984/v69wd/2/

With Containers to avoid inverse property handling: http://jsfiddle.net/ccarterc1984/v69wd/3/

I changed the img to div since I didn't have any images handy.  This fires off one at a time, and it added margin-top in conjunction with the height decrease to get the effect I think you are looking for.

HTML:

```
<div id="inline-blocked-images">
    <div id="one" class="box"></div>
    <div id="two" class="box"></div>
    <div id="three" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#one, #two, #three{
    background-color: blue;
    position:relative;
    display:none;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.box').each(function(boxIndex){
    var box = $(this);
    setTimeout( function (boxIndex) {
        animateBox(box);
    }, boxIndex * 2000);   
});

function animateBox(box){
    box.show();
    box.animate( { 'width':50, 'height':50, 'margin-top':50}, 2000);   
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This technique worked for me. Essentially each div/image is put inside a container of its own which is fixed dimension. Hence when you animate a div/img inside the fixed dimension div it works as expected. I ended up using the div too with content:url(../myimage.png). I somehow couldn't get this to work with pure img tag though.

Comment: Ah..I must be making a mistake at the time. Cool. Thanks carter

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will work for you

```
function showImage(image)
{
    var el = (!image)? $('#inline-blocked-images img:first') : image;
    $(el).show();
    $(el).animate( { 'width':50, 'height':50}, {duration:200});
    nextImage = el.next();
    if(nextImage)
    {
        setTimeout(function(){ showImage(nextImage)}, 2000);
    }
}

 setTimeout(function(){ showImage()}, 1000);
```

Set your images to `float: left`

See here http://fiddle.jshell.net/R4TaM/1/

Comment: Your fiddle indeed shows the effect I am looking for but I accepted Carter's answer because I could make that code work for me easily. Nothing wrong with the answer just where my code was initially simply changing float:left wasn't working for me.